# How can I use a struct in a gorm model struct without it being a model

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a model struct

```
type Customer struct {
    gorm.Model
    Person  `gorm:"-" json:"person"`
    Contact `gorm:"-" json:"contact"`
    Address `gorm:"-" json:"address"`
}

func (p Customer) Validate() error {
    return validation.ValidateStruct(&p,
        validation.Field(&p.Person),
        validation.Field(&p.Contact),
        validation.Field(&p.Address),
    )
}
```

I want the customer to have Contact data so I have a contact struct. But whenever I try to run the server

```
type Contact struct {
    Tel  string `json:"tel"`
    Mail string `json:"mail"`
    URL  string `json:"url"`
}

func (c Contact) Validate() error {
    return validation.ValidateStruct(&c,
        validation.Field(&c.Tel, validation.Required, is.Digit),
        validation.Field(&c.Mail, validation.Required, is.Email),
        validation.Field(&c.URL, is.URL),
    )
}
```

I get

```
model.Customer's field Contact, need to define a foreign key for relations or it need to implement the Valuer/Scanner interface
```

But I don't want it to be on it's own seperate table. So how do I prevent that? I tried using

```
`gorm:"-"`
```

But if I then read the record as json all the values are empty

```
    "contact": {
        "tel": "",
        "mail": "",
        "url": ""
    },
```

So my question is why do I need the scanner and valuer or a foreign key if I don't want it to be on it's own seperate table?

Comment: Have you tried adding both gorm and json tags ? `gorm:"-" json:"tel"`

Comment: Yes adding it to the Contact field of Customer seems to get rid of the error but the but when I read the record all contacts fields are still empty strings. I tried adding it to the fields in Contact aswell but doen't seem to work

Comment: just to make it clear, `Tel`, `Mail` and `URL` are part of the `customers` table, but you want to load them into the `Contact` property of the `Customer` struct, along with other data from the `customers` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use gorm:"embedded" instead of gorm:"-" as described in the docs

https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#Embedded-Struct